# Geometric sequences, given the formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

a.  Is the following a Geometric Sequence:
$a_n = 4 \times 4^{n-1}$

b.  Is the following a Geometric Sequence:
$a_n = 5 + 2n$

c.   Given the following Geometric Sequence, find the 6th term:
$5, 30, 180, 1080 \dots$

d.  Given the following Geometric Sequence, find the 8th term:
$a_n = 2 \times 5^{n-1}$

I'm confused on a. How do I determine if it is a geometric sequence? By substituting values in to see if it has the same ratio? Because I think it is a geo sequence.

Comment: The $n$s should cancel when you take the ratio so you can just use $\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}$.

Comment: as john said a,c,d are geometric sequences but d is not.

Comment: do I just plug numbers in to see if it is a geometric sequence?